# Can a field value from one table be used as a column name in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Say I have two tables:

```
mysql> show columns from profiles;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| full_name    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| date_of_birth| date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> select * from profiles;
+-------------------+----------------+
| id  | full_name   | date_of_birth  |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| 1   | John Smith  | 2000-01-01     |
| 2   | Anna Smith  | 1995-01-03     |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

and

```
mysql> show columns from language_en;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| column_name  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| label        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> select * from language_en;
+-------------------+----------------+
| column_name      | label           |
+------------------+-----------------+
| id               | ID              |
| full_name        | Name            |
| date_of_birth    | DOB             |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to run a query that returns:

```
+-------------------+----------------+
| ID  | Name        | DOB            |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| 1   | John Smith  | 2000-01-01     |
| 2   | Anna Smith  | 1995-01-03     |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

Which is just the query "SELECT * FROM profiles" but using the labels instead of the column names. How do I do this using the column names and not entering them directly?
I know I can do:

```
SELECT id AS ID, full_name AS Name, date_of_birth AS DOB FROM profiles
```

However I was after something dynamic like:

```
SELECT id AS language_en.label FROM profiles, language_en WHERE language_en.column_name = profiles.COLUMN_HEADER????
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: I don't think so. I don't think MySQL's AS statement accepts anything other than a simple text label.

I think putting your internationalization into the database schema level is probably the wrong idea; it seems like you can keep your life more sane by keeping that translation level in your web application (php) layer. After all, your users should never need to see directly what the name of your columns are, right?

Comment: Yeah I'm not really using internationalization just thought it would make a good example for what I am trying to do, I just want to use the returned data to create a HTML form and use the labels I have set instead of the ugly database field names.

Comment: Ah, ok -- sorry. Well, the immediate answer to your question remains the same. In the mysql "SELECT <field> AS <alias> ..." statement, the field alias can only be a string. I think it only accepts characters like [A-Za-z0-9_]. You can quickly verify that any attempt to do anything complicated in the AS alias results in a syntax exception, such as: select 5+5 as (select 10);. You could use a VIEW to change column names, but that would also change how you query the fields. I'd recommend changing your display text at a higher level: in your php code.

Comment: Yeah currently changing it in PHP